# jQuery ajax is breaking my Divi theme. How do I fix it?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o29gj.png)I am currently working on a project where my script adds the schema codex into the navigation. The `jQuery` code does work.

However, when I add the link for ajax.googleapis.com it break all other Divi style scripts. I would be grateful for any help! Please view my coding below. I have this in a child theme and the code is stored in a `functions.php` file.

The theme builder I am working with is Div.

```
<?php


function load_js()
{

    if(!is_admin())
   { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';

      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){

    // Put itemscope and itemtype into navigation ul
    $("nav ul").attr("itemscope", "").attr("itemtype", "http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement");
    // put itemprop in lis
    $("nav ul li").attr("itemprop", "name");
    //put itemprop url in anchors
    $("nav ul li a").attr("itemprop", "url");

}); 

 </script>';
   }


}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_js');
```

Comment: Where is the closing tag of your `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: They are there. When I put them into the text editor above it took them out for some reason. I will see if I can do a screen shot.

Comment: That was cool! Sorry, still learning how to use this! Thanks @Samuel!

Comment: @JoshuaTrimm no problem man, welcome to SO!

Comment: if you remove jquery, it doesn't affect anything? I think jquery is already included in wordpress. You just have to include it.

Comment: When I remove src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js the script no longer works and the divi builder works fine again.

Comment: try to add this `function theme_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');`. Call this function first before your other function..

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same results. @ShadowFiend I tried with ajax and without.

Answer (score 0):

After think on it and working on some other projects, I have accomplished and fixed the problem.

The issue was that the script to pull in the ajax jquery library was being loaded into the  and not the . So I made some simple changes you can view below to see the fix.

```
    <?php


    function load_js()
    {

        if(!is_admin())
       { 

          echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function(){

        // Put itemscope and itemtype into navigation ul
        $("nav ul").attr("itemscope", "").attr("itemtype", "http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement");
        // put itemprop in lis
        $("nav ul li").attr("itemprop", "name");
        //put itemprop url in anchors
        $("nav ul li a").attr("itemprop", "url");

    });  
</script>';
       }


    }

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_js');

// load ajax jquery for schema nav
function ajax_jquery()
{
    if(!is_admin())
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    }
}
add_action( 'et_head_meta', 'ajax_jquery');
```

Thanks everyone for your help!